# SSRS rdlc report causing build to silently fail in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reporting-services

One of our developers gets the following build error when trying to build a project in Visual Studio 2013 that contains an rdlc file, developed in VS 2012:

> Error 1 Could not copy the file "C:[...].Core.dll" because it was not
>   found. C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 3797 5
>   [...]

From this [link](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2006/07/06/build-failed-with-no-errors.aspx) we tracked it to the rdlc report - and excluding the rdlc file does allow us to build the project successfully. However we can add new reports that compile fine, and all the reporting dlls are present in the GAC.

Another one of our developers has the same version of Visual Studio (2013) and is building the same version of the application with no problems. The only difference we can see is that the .net versions are slightly different (Version 4.5.51209 versus 4.5.50938).

Finally, when the user who cannot compile the existing rdlc adds a new rdlc file, the report header is (2008 schema):

```
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
```

But the existing reports, added in VS 2012 have this (2010 schema):

```
<Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns:cl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/componentdefinition" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition">
```

So it looks like the VS 2013 is stuck using an older version of SSRS? Any advice on this would be very welcome.

Comment: I think the mismatch is probably connected to the version of ReportViewer that has been installed on a given machine.  This post is not a direct hit, but it should shed some light on what I'm suggesting: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/20212689-20da-4315-8fb3-7190b4b93628/converting-an-rdlc-report-from-vs-2008-to-vs-2010

Comment: Thank you, we'll try Amit's suggestion of replacing the 2010 header with 2008